# Error importing object in scala

Tags: eclipse, scala

I am learning to program in Scala. I have two packages named `chapter3` and `chapter4`. Below is the code:

Code for the file `FileOperation.scala` in package `chapter3`:

```
package chapter3

import scala.io.Source

object FileOperation {

  /**
   * This function determines the length of line length.
   */
  def findLineLengthWidth(line : String) : Int = {
    val len = line.length.toString.length()
    return len;
  }

  def readFile(filename : String) {
    val lines = Source.fromFile(filename).getLines().toList
    val longestLine = lines.reduceLeft((a, b) => if(a.length > b.length) a else b)
    val maxlength = findLineLengthWidth(longestLine)

    for (line <- lines) {
      val len = findLineLengthWidth(line)
      val spacecount = (maxlength - len)
      val padding = " " * spacecount
      println(padding + line.length +"|"+ line)
    }
  }
}
```

code for file in chapter4 package: Summer.scala

```
package chapter4

import chapter3.FileOperation._

object Summer {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    {
      //val file = new FileOperation
      readFile("abc.txt")
    } 
  }
}
```

When I run this code in Eclipse, it works fine. However when I try to compile it in the terminal, I get the following error:

```
$ scalac *.scala
Summer.scala:3: error: not found: object chapter3
import chapter3.FileOperation._
       ^
Summer.scala:11: error: not found: value readFile
      readFile("abc.txt")
      ^
two errors found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your directory structure is:

```
chapter3/FileOperation.scala
chapter4/Summer.scala
```

Then, from the parent directory run:

```
scalac chapter3/FileOperation.scala chapter4/Summer.scala
```

This compiles just fine. If you want to compile them individually, make sure `FileOperation` is first, because `Summer` depends on it.

Once it's compiled, you can run it with:

```
scala -cp .:chapter3:chapter4 chapter4.Summer
```

Comment: It compiled with 
    scalac chapter3/FileOperation.scala chapter4/Summer.scala

However when I try to run, I get following error:
    >scala chapter4/Summer
    No such file or class on classpath: chapter4/Summer

Comment: @user1247412 You need to have a concept of java classpath in order to run Scala program in terminal using `scala` command directly. Otherwise you will have to use building tools(Eclipse / SBT...) that have already setup classpath for you.

Comment: This will run your program: scala -cp .:chapter3:chapter4 chapter4.Summer

Comment: Isn't there any simple way to compile and run the files from different packages?

Comment: Think of it in terms of 1) compiling everything that you pass to the compiler, 2) then putting everything that resulted on your classpath, and 3) running a single object that has a main() method. Your example above already uses 2 packages.